# Converting the structure of input data in R

Tags: r

Below is the structures of my dataframe:

```
'data.frame':   213 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ up_entrez: Factor w/ 143 levels "101739","108077",...: 3 94 125 103 3 34 3 37 134 13 ...
 $ Ratio    : num  3.1 3.37 1.8 1.21 6.92 ....
```

and I want to convert it to something like this for the function to take it as an input:

```
Named num [1:12495] 4.57 4.51 4.42 4.14 3.88 ....
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:12495] "4312" "8318" "10874" "55143" ....
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `setNames` to create a named vector

```
v1 <- with(df1, setNames(Ratio, up_entrez))
```